# Cookies wont work in https:// why?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web

what is different when we open url with https/http w.r.t Cookies?
What is code/mechanism behind  https:/..............Url........ and http://...url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Domain, Secure, and HttpOnline properties, as they can be used to restrict which urls will receive which cookies from the client. The [Wikipedia article on cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some help: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/7475.htm

To sum it up, https and http are considered different domains, so you can't access the cookies from one on the other.  If you set the cookie to secure though, the https should be able to read it.

Comment: I don't think it's true that, for cookie access, "http" and "https" are treated separately, *unless* cookies are created with the "secure" flag.  Ordinary non-secure cookies are available to pages based on domain name alone.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my post.  I believe he created a cookie on his secure page and cant access it on his http content pages